# If a sequence of distributions converges to a degenerate, does that imply the variance strictly decreases?

Tags: distributions, probability

If $F_i = G(F_{i-1}), F_0 = x$ is a sequence of distributions that converges to a degenerate distribution as $i \to \infty$, does that imply that the variance of $F_i$ decreases with $i$?

Specifically, I am interested in the inverse Kumaraswamy distribution: $G(x) = (1-(1-x)^a)^b$ when $a=b$... Note that $G$ produces the cdf of the Max of b draws from the distribution of the Min of a draws from its argument (which is going to be a cdf).

So if it's not true for the general case, but you have insights on how/why it would be true in this case, I would appreciate it.  I can intuit (and graph for specific values of a) that the mean and variance decrease in this case -- taking the Min of $a$ draws from $F$ decreases the mean, then taking the max of $a=b$ draws from the new distribution increases the mean, but not by as much as the first operation lowered it, so the final mean is less than that of the original.   But I am shaky on how to prove it (and my other questions today have basically been trying to get at this point).

PS -- sorry to overload with questions today!  As I mentioned, they've all been in the goal of this question here.

Comment: Converges in what sense?  (The answer in the general case depends on the topology!)

Comment: @whuber.  Oh boy.  This may be way out of my league.  What I mean is, at the limit as $i \to \infty, F_i = 0 \text{ if x < L}, 1 \text{ if }x \geq L$ where L is a constant within the bounds of $F$ (and I also only care about F being supported over 0, 1). Does that answer the question?

Comment: In general, no, of course not. Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be zero-mean normal random variables with variances $\sigma_i^2$. Choose any sequence of $\sigma_i^2 \geq 0$ such that $\sigma_i^2 \to 0$. (The point being, there is no need for $\sigma_i^2$ to be monotone.)

Comment: If you assume *all* the $F_i$ are supported in $[0,1]$, then the variance will have to converge to 0.  If you only assume the *limiting* distribution is supported in $[0,1]$, then the variances do *not* have to converge!  (Consider a mixture of a uniform and a Normal distribution, with the location of the Normal distribution diverging faster than the inverse square of its mixture weight.)

Comment: After reading my comments and @whuber, it becomes apparent to me that there are at least two ways this question can be read as currently written. :) (My comments have also been colored by the title of this question.)

Comment: @cardinal I think your reading is more accurate (if I have understood it correctly :-)), but it seems to lead to questions of little interest or utility.  Because convergence of a sequence of distributions is independent of the phenomenon "decreases with $i$", the two should have no relationship with one another.  In fact, swapping every other term in a monotonically convergent sequence won't change its convergence properties at all but it ruins monotonicity...

Comment: @cardinal:  I am sorry for being slow.  I don't understand how the question can be interpreted other than I mean it, so of course that is not helpful.  I think what I gathering from comments is that if all the distributions are supported (0,1) then the variance will converge to 0, however, even if that is the case, the variances may not be monotone, so I cannot say they strictly decrease.  Is that correct?  If so, any insights on my particular distribution?  (I keep trying to ask general case questions, but really, all I need is this one particular case)

Comment: @whuber: Yes, I agree. I just figured that the OP might have been confused about this very point. (Hence, my comment.) It *does* seem that no matter what the OP is interested in, it does deal with convergence to a degenerate distribution, so the support of the limiting distribution also seems like it may be of rather marginal interest.

Comment: @whuber:  yes, I think I get that now.  Thank you.  Still I think there is something about the specific function such that this is true, however I can't seem to get at it by finding general principles.  And the question has interest/utility to me, even if only in understanding why it is wrong, and how to better think about the concepts at hand.

Comment: @whuber:  I am interested, though, in what other senses of converge there can be.

Comment: @JandR: You're not being slow. We're just trying to figure out the real question of interest. If a sequence of random variables converges to a degenerate distribution, then the variance of the limiting distribution will be zero. However, I believe the variances of the random variables in the sequence need not even be defined. Take, for example, a sequence of Cauchy distributions with a scale parameter converging to zero.

Comment: @cardinal:  Ok.  Thank you.  The REAL question of interest (to me) is:  how to prove that both the mean and variance of $F_i$ as defined above decrease with $i$? Everything else I ask is just my (probably convoluted) way of going about it since I did not get very far trying to do it through calculus.

Comment: @JandR: Do you know that to actually be true? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @cardinal:  also, re: do I know it's true -- I made a simulation program that approximates the expectations for all sorts of different parameters, and it always holds.  But that's still not proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is a simple counterexample.**

Assume the CDF $F$ is supported on $[0,1]$ and define a new CDF $G[F]$ as follows.  If $\mathbb{E}[F] \gt 1/2$, let

$$G[F](x) = 1 - F(3/2 - 2 x).$$

Otherwise, let

$$G[F](x) = 1 - F(5/6 - 2x/3).$$

The first operation squeezes the distribution by a factor of $2$ towards $1/2$ and flips it around $1/2$, while the second expands the distribution by a factor of $3/2$ away from $1/2$ and also flips it around $1/2$.  The flipping guarantees that if the mean of $F$ is other than $1/2$, then iterating $G$ will alternate between these two operations, because the expectations will alternately be greater than and less than $1/2$.  The net result nevertheless is to compress the support down towards $1/2$, converging to a degenerate distribution.  However, the variance in the first case is multiplied by $1/4$ and in the second case it is multiplied by $9/4$, whence it does not uniformly decrease: it alternately jumps up and down.  Therefore convergence of a sequence of distributions $(G^n[F])$ to an atom does not imply monotonic decrease of the variances.

Answer (score 3):

You ask for intuition.  Maybe the following bit of hand-waving will help.

Provided $F$ is continuous, your particular sequence, $G^n[F]$ with $G[F](x) = (1-(1-F(x))^a)^a$, indeed eventually has monotonically decreasing variances because $G$ is a smooth contracting map.  Specifically, $G$ has a fixed point $x_0$ (the unique root of $G[x]=x$ in the interval $(0,1)$) and *it contracts all values towards that fixed point.*

[image: Figure]

*(The figure shows $F(x)=x$ and the first three iterations of $G$ for $a=2$.)*

This alone is not enough for an easy proof (I don't think), but notice in addition that the derivative of $G$ near that fixed point always strictly exceeds $1$.  (It is never smaller at the fixed point than $6 - 2\sqrt{5} \approx 1.528$, when $a=2$.)  After enough iterations, almost all the probability is squeezed into a region near this fixed point, where $G$ acts essentially as a rescaling operation, which will shrink the variance at each step.  (Any probability outside this small neighborhood cannot contribute much to the variance because the support of $G^n[F]$ is bounded independent of $n$.) The shrinking means the variance eventually behaves almost like a geometric series with common ratio $1/G'(x_0)^2$, which will monotonically decrease.  I think a little epsilon-delta analysis could make this argument rigorous.